# Java. How to remove white space on array

Tags: java

For example
I split a string "+name" by +. I got an white space" " and the "name" in the array(this doesn't happen if my string is "name+").

```
t="+name";
String[] temp=t.split("\\+");
```

the above code produces

```
temp[0]=" "
temp[1]=name
```

I only wants to get "name" without whitespace..

Also if t="name+" then temp[0]=name.  I'm wondering what is difference between name+ and +name. Why do I get different output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply loop thru the items in array like the one below and remove white space

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    temp[i] = if(!temp[i].trim().equals("") || temp[i]!=null)temp[i].trim();
}
```

Comment: is this able to trim the element if the element itself is white space? or it only remove the white space if the string contains white

Comment: it only removes the white space

Comment: It produces null value instead of white space in the array.

Comment: ok..do one thing just check for null's.Replace this one if(array[i].trim().equals("")){ with this one if(array[i] == null){

Comment: still null value. I don't know why I get white space when I split the string"+name" but doesn't get the white space for string"name+".

Comment: edit your question and post your code so that i can analyze your code

Answer (score 1):

The value of the first array item is *not a space (`" "`) but an empty string (`""`)*. The following snippet demonstrates the behaviour and provides a workaround: I simply strip leading delimiters from the input. Note, that this should never be used for processing csv files, because a leading delimiter will create an empty column value which is usually wanted.

```
    for (String s : "+name".split("\\+")) {
        System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (String s : "name+".split("\\+")) {
        System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (String s : "+name".replaceAll("^\\+", "").split("\\+")) {
        System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s);
    }
```

Comment: what if the the string is "+++++name" or "firstname+++lastname" but I only want the name and firstname lastname. is there any good way to handle this?

Comment: Sure. The delimiter is nothing but a regular expression. Use `\\++` if you want to split around one or more plusses.

Answer (score 1):

You get the extra element for `"+name"`'s case is because of non-empty value "name" after the delimiter.

The `split()` function only "trims" the trailing delimiters that result to empty elements at the end of an array. See [JavaSE Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Examples of `.split("\\+")` output:

```
"+++++"     = { }                // zero length array because all are trailing delimiters
"+name+"    = { "", "name" }     // trailing delimiter removed
"name+++++" = { "name" }         // trailing delimiter removed
"name+"     = { "name" }         // trailing delimiter removed
"++name+"   = { "", "", "name" } // trailing delimiter removed
```

---

I would suggest preventing to have those extra delimiters on both ends rather than *cleaning up* afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

to remove white space

```
str.replaceAll("\\W","").
```

Comment: This doesn't work because "+name" doesn't have white space. but when split the "+name" by + I got a white space in the array

Comment: you are removing white space from your string then  your are spiting using loop.

Comment: this string "+name" doesn't have white space.

Comment: but when I split this string by array=string.split("\\+"). I got a white space in array[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "name +";
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\W", "");
yourArray = yourString.split("\\+");
```

Comment: This doesn't work because "+name" doesn't have white space. but when split the "+name" by + I got a white space in the arra

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work with you. But if you try to take a look at this code, it actually works. String str = "name +";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\W", "");
        String[] array = str.split("\\+");
        for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner :

```
String temp[] = t.replaceAll("(^\\++)?(\\+)?(\\+*)?", "$2").split("\\+");
```

This will replace all multiple plus signs by one, or a plus sign at the start by empty String, and then split on plus signs.
Which will basically eliminate empty Strings in the result.

`split(String regex)` is equivalent to `split(String regex, int limit)` with limit = 0. And the documentation of the latter states :

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Which is why a `'+'` at the start works differently than a `'+'` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give guavas [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) a try. It has a nice fluent api to deal with emptyStrings, trim(), etc.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final String t1 = "+name";
    final String t2 = "name+";

    assertThat(split(t1), hasSize(1));
    assertThat(split(t1).get(0), is("name"));

    assertThat(split(t2), hasSize(1));
    assertThat(split(t2).get(0), is("name"));
}

private List<String> split(final String sequence) {
    final Splitter splitter = Splitter.on("+").omitEmptyStrings().trimResults();
    return Lists.newArrayList(splitter.split(sequence));
}
```